# Resources.resx not loading in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to make my application multilingual. For this I have created two resource files:

- Resource.de-DE.resx
- Resource.en-US.resx

Both are set to public and contain the same keyword and translation. I can also access the keywords in the backend -> see image.
Unfortunately my program does not load the files when I change the language.

My steps:

1. set the default Resources.resx to public.
2. copied this file twice
3. renamed file to (see above)
4. keywords+translation entered and checked
5. project created again
6. included on the Button-Content by:

```
<Button x:Name="Home_Button" Style="{DynamicResource Menuebutton}"  Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Menue_home}" Click="Home_Click"/>
```

7. access of the object set by:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:VS_Launcher.Properties"
```

8. include in the MainWindow.xaml.cs by:

```
CultureInfo myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = myCultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = myCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = myCultureInfo;
```

In another project I did the same thing. But there the solution worked. What is my error?

[Resource Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctI8T.png)
[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwjNv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the file names of alternative language resources (excluding culture-locale) are identical with default one? If the default one is Resource`s`.resx, alternative ones must be like:

- Resource`s`.de-DE.resx
- Resource`s`.en-US.resx

Comment: On my other Project there was no need to do it. It worked fine with Resource.de-DE.resx
Thats strange.

However name the Files like you did fixed the Problem. Thanks :)

Comment: If so, in other project, the default one must be Resource.resx.